# GeometryReader returns different values for top level view on simulator vs phone (SE 2nd generation)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I've been trying to chase down problems in my swiftUI app with differences between simulator and my actual phone and I've boiled it down to this - even with a dirt simple 1 view app, GeometryReader is returning a different value on my phone than in the simulator for the same phone model (iPhone SE 2nd generation)

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gc in
      let h = gc.size.height
      let w = gc.size.width
      Text("h = \(h), w=\(w)")
    }
  }
}
```

On the simulator, I get a height of 647 and a width of 375

On the phone, I get a height of 548 and a width of 320

I've turned off every zoom feature on the phone that I can find - all accessibility features are turned off - and even rebooted the phone. All my other apps look normal.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom on the physical device.

I was able to reproduce the problem on an iPhone 8 when Display Zoom was set to Larger Text instead of Default. I don't think this setting is available on a simulator.

Also, it might be worth checking Per-App Settings under Settings > Accessibility, in case there is a setting that has only been turned on for the app you are testing.

Comment: I thought I had reset the Display & Brightness Zoom, but I guess I had not successfully reset it. But is there a way to make SwiftUI ignore that zoom setting? For this application, that is what is desired.

Comment: I would expect that this setting affects all apps on the device, so you won't be able to override it programmatically from the app. Since it is under Display & Brightness (as opposed to it being an Accessibility setting) I don't even think you can add a Per-App setting to override it.